# nodejs azure-storage blob service does not fire its callback

Tags: node.js, azure-storage

I am using nodejs azure-storage NPM package to access and upload files to azure storage.

The problem i am facing is, the callback method of blobService.createContainerIfNotExists() method is not firing. Code appears to hang. Event the next statement to this call does not execute.
below is my code.

```
      var azure = require('azure-storage');
      var path = ure = require('path');
      var _dir = process.cwd();

      process.env.AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT = "ezcollaborate";
      process.env.AZURE_STORAGE_ACCESS_KEY = "qYwtbk/eI8gd+gO5+IOzEKBAixXDXBTiUd5s6Ar7xYUdbscqDflsYh887Glw/BYv1FfWnHWv4Kr71NS1wqTtkA==";
      var azureBlobUrl = "https://ezcollaborate.blob.core.windows.net/gallery/";

      module.exports = function(){
        var blobService = azure.createBlobService();
        var _checkContainer  = function(options, cb){
            if(options.container == null || options.container == "" ){

               options.container = "gallery"; 
            }
            var containerName =options.container; 

            blobService.createContainerIfNotExists(containerName, {publicAccessLevel : 'blob'},function(err, result, response) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log("Couldn't create container %s", containerName);
                    console.error(err);
                } else {
                    if (result) {
                        console.log('Container %s created', containerName);
                    } else {
                        console.log('Container %s already exists', containerName);
                    }

                    // Your code goes here
                }
            });
    }

    return {
        checkContainer:_checkContainer,
        uploadStream : _uploadFileFromStream
    }

  };
```

I have tried other methods like createBlockBlobFromLocalFile and listContainersSegmented but those behave same.

has anyone faced similar issue?
Above access key is real key, feel free to try it out.